# Resin 4 Windows service name is always "Resin Web Server"

Tags: windows-server-2003, application-server, resin

I'm trying to run multiple Resin 4 service instances on a Windows Server 2003 box which means each service name must be unique so I can determine which one of the many that I need to start/stop or restart when changes occur.

According to the Resin 4 docs (http://www.caucho.com/resin/install/install.xtp#Installing%20Resin%20as%20a%20Windows%20Service) a service can be uniquely named with a flag -install-as {service name}:
C:\Resin\resin.exe -install-as ResinA

Unfortunately, the service name always appears as "Resin Web Server" regardless of what you replace "ResinA" with. So I end up with several "Resin Web Server" instances and have to view the properties of each to see what arguments were passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a service's display name in regedit by going to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services, locating the service you want to change, and adjusting the DisplayName value.  You may need to reboot for this to take effect.  ([Clicky](http://www.techbytes.ca/techbyte73.html))

Beware of this however: there may be other settings contained in ini or cfg files associated with the service that also contain a display name which needs to be the same, and - if you're really unlucky - an executable associated with your service may have the name hardcoded in.  From the sound of things your services will play nice with the latter, but I would definitely advise checking the former.

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat (I know, not same thing, but they set up similarly) it's originally set up via a batch file, and you set service name and display name separately, like below:

-set SERVICE_NAME=Tomcat5
  -set PR_DISPLAYNAME=Apache Tomcat